# Syntax Error: Unexpected EOF while parsing - Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing, eof

I am using python to try and print the following table, where the values for each joint are located within a 9x1 numpy array, t. I continue to receive the error SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF while parsing. I have attempted to index t various ways and continue to get the same error. Here is my print code, as well as 't' and what I would like the table to look like.

```
print("            tension         compression \nJoint A    {0:4.0f}          {1:4.0f} \nJoint B    {2:4.0f}          {3:4.0f} \nJoint C    {4:4.0f}          {5:4.0f} \nJoint D    {6:4.0f}          {7:4.0f} \nJoint E    {8:4.0f}          {9:4.0f}".format(t[0],t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5],t[6],t[7],t[8],t[9])

t = [ 3500.         -4041.5704388   2020.7852194  -3464.20323326  2886.83602771
  1732.10161663  2598.15242494 -5196.30484988  4500.        ]

            tension         compression 
Joint A 
Joint B 
Joint C 
Joint D 
Joint E
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You are missing a closing parenthesis when calling `print`.
2. You use `t[0]`...`t[9]` before you even define `t`.
3. `t` is defined as a "normal" Python list but using an invalid syntax. Python can't guess that you want `t` to be a numpy array. You need it to tell it that.

   ```
   import numpy as np

   t = np.array([3500., -4041.5704388, 2020.7852194, -3464.20323326, 2886.83602771,
                 1732.10161663, 2598.15242494, -5196.30484988, 4500.])
   ```
4. `t` only contains 9 elements but you try to access the 10<sup>th</sup> (`t[9]`).

Also, it seems like you are trying to reinvent pandas dataframe.